# Call jpanel form from jFrame form with parameter in java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, drag-and-drop

I am working in jpanel form (drag and drop ) in netbeans. From jframe form i want to call a jpanel form and want to pass parent frame as parameter . How can I do that in drag and drop in netbeans ?

Comment: Why do you need the parent? Note that since `JPanel` inherits from `JComponent` you can always get the parent components at runtime. Alteratively (I don't know whether with "drag and drop" you mean a GUI editor or not) you should be able to add your own code next to the auto-generated one and thus set properties of any component manually (if needed).

Comment: Actually panel is not directly in the jFrame . There are some nested panel. And component is at the bottom from where I want Frame

Comment: *"Actually panel is not directly in the jFrame"*  Is that supposed to mean 'so I can't do what you are suggesting'?  Please don't presume we know that you are thinking.  Be specific!  Not many people around here enjoy playing '20 questions'.

Comment: @Andrew agreed @Diptopol as I said, you can get the parents (as in parent and grand parents), i.e. you can walk up the hierarchy until you found the `JFrame` no matter how deeply nested your component is.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the parent component of a Swing component using `getParent()`.

See [Component.getParent()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent%28%29) for details.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the formatting, will take care of doing that myself next time.

Comment: You're welcome, but it was just something I did when updating the link to point to the Java 7 docs.  7 might not be official, but we might as well start linking to them, since they will not change now.

Answer (score 1):

In the gui editor, you can edit the custom creation code to call a constructor of your choice. Your panel must still have a no argument blank constructor as it is a bean.

right click your panel->properties->code->custom creation code.

new MyPanel(this)

Or get the parent as mentioned.